Jupyter Notebook export issue with images in VS Code and standalone application
I'm experiencing problems exporting Jupyter Notebooks to PDF or HTML using both VS Code and the standalone Jupyter Notebook application. The issue occurs specifically when I try to include images in my notebooks.
Problem Description

Exporting works fine for plain text or code cells.
As soon as I attempt to insert an image, the export fails.
This problem occurs in both VS Code and the standalone Jupyter Notebook application.

Attempts Made

Inserting images as HTML code:
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="Images\Hydraulic_inductor_model.svg.png" alt="fishy" style="width: 20%;">
</div>

(Using both backslashes and forward slashes)

Inserting images as markdown code:
![Image](Images\Hydraulic_inductor_model.svg.png)

![Image](Images/Hydraulic_inductor_model.svg.png)

(Using both backslashes and forward slashes)

Using brute force mode worked out but it is not a real solution :
![image.png](attachment:image.png)



Additional Information

Reinstalled Jupyter Notebook
Reinstalled nbconvert
Tried using absolute paths
Verified file permissions

Expected Behavior
The export should successfully include images in the output PDF or HTML file.
Actual Behavior
The export fails when attempting to include images, regardless of the method used.
Is there a known issue or workaround for this problem? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Note
I am not a expert programmer, so please be clear and explain in a way that a that also a not-deep-code-nerd can understand, thanks!
